# Regex need match first path in string not subsequent

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regex that will match the first line, but not the second. This is what I have `/^github.com\/[^\\\n]+$/`

```
github.com/reggi
github.com/reggi/example
```

https://regexr.com/3ld7o

```js
var patternA = /^github.com\/[^\\\n]+$/
var patternB = /^github\.com\/.+/
var patternC = /^github.com\/[^\/\n]+$/

var examples = function (pattern) {
  return [
    !!'github.com/reggi/genesis/soup'.match(pattern),
    !!'github.com/reggi/genesis'.match(pattern),
    !!'github.com/reggi'.match(pattern),
  ]
}

console.log(examples(patternA))
console.log(examples(patternB))
console.log(examples(patternC))
```

Comment: `!!'...'.match(pattern)` -> `pattern.test('...')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^github.com\/[^\/\n]+$
```

I think you just had the wrong type of slash escaped.

https://regexr.com/3ld8v

Comment: If that was the case, it would not select `github.com/reggi/genesis/soup` https://regexr.com/3ld8j

Comment: I see. I thought you were concerned with matching on separate lines. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `/^github\.com\/.+/` is enough for your need (remember to uncheck `m` - multiline when you test with regexr.com).

https://regexr.com/3ld7u

Comment: If that was the case, it would not select `github.com/reggi/genesis/soup` https://regexr.com/3ld8j